# Visual Basic: CallByName with multiple "Levels"

Tags: vba, callbyname

I've been working on this for quite a bit now but I still cannot get my code going.

I have a class called `Contact` which has a read-only property `Address`. The `Address` class has properties like `Street` and `City`. Now I want to assign a contact's street like this:

```
CallByName(contact, "Address.Street", CallType.Set, new_street)
```

But I am getting an error saying "Address.Street" is not a member of `Contact`.

I need to set the property via its name so

```
contact.Adress.Street = new_street
```

is not an option.

How can I make the first example above work?

Comment: Try CallByName(contact.Address, "Street", CallType.Let, new_street)

Comment: "I need to set the property via its name" ..uh, sure, except nothing in your code justifies it. Care to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

`CallByName` makes *one* call. You want to make two.

First a call to the getter:

```
Dim contactAddress As Address
Set contactAddress = CallByName(contact, "Address", CallType.Get)
```

Then, ..well then there's no reason to `CallByName` to assign the `Street` property value:

```
contactAddress.Street = new_street
```