# CallByName with multiple levels of properties

Tags: html, vba, callbyname

I want to use CallByName in VBA to read a specific data from such webpages. Those webpages have different html structures. In my case, there is a element that I need to refer 2 or 3 parent nodes and get an element with  or  tags. See the code:

element in all webpages I named `MyElem`

in one webpage I need this code:

```
MsgBox MyElem.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getelementsbytagname("tr")(3).innertext
```

in another webpage I need this code:

```
MsgBox MyElem.parentElement.parentElement.getelementsbytagname("div")(2).innertext
```

and so on ...

I want to write in VBA as below:

```
Select Case Webpage
     Case "webpage_1"
        property ="parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getelementsbytagname("tr")(3).innertext"
     Case "webpage_2"
        property = "parentElement.parentElement.getelementsbytagname("div")(2).innertext"

      ' and so on ...

 End Select

MsgBox CallByName(MyElem, property, VbGet)
```

The problem is that CallByName don't support multiple levels of properties.
I read similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809480/visual-basic-callbyname-with-multiple-levels) but it doesn't help to my case. Is there any idea?

Comment: It would help if you share HTML samples and expected outcomes. There may be a better way. And as you already have a Select Case why not just put your selector direct in there?

Comment: Unfortunately the webpages are in private. Your idea about css selector is good and I think it is better. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
Dim res

Select Case Webpage
     Case "webpage_1"
        res = MyElem.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getelementsbytagname("tr")(3).innertext
     Case "webpage_2"
        res = MyElem.parentElement.parentElement.getelementsbytagname("div")(2).innertext

      ' and so on ...

 End Select

MsgBox res
```

Comment: I can't use this way, because the element "MyElem" created after Case.

Comment: So create it before ?  Or wrap the select in a function, passing in MyElem as an argument.

Comment: I should try it. Is there any way to use CallByName to set an object to another? Like this: `Set obj = CallByName(MyElem,property,VbSet)` If it is possible I can make final object which has multiple levels of properties.

Comment: Yes - it would be `Set obj = CallByName(MyElem,property, VbGet)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Function PropDotVal(wObjName$, PropNa$)
```

Dim wObj As Object: Set wObj = ObjFromStr(wObjName)

'  ObjFromStr in module with lines like
' there has got to be an inbuilt  vba function  that does not need many case functions
'       str                       obj
'Case "sTable": Set ObjFromStr = sTable ' ShapePlus
'Case "WHCages": Set ObjFromStr = WHCages ' spt

Dim Si%, NaA$()
PropDotVal = "NA"
On Error GoTo NotAvailable
NaA = Split(PropNa, ".")

If UBound(NaA) > 0 Then

```
  ' PropNa format multi like  wObj.Objb.objc  etc  .prop
  '  convert wObj as  FredsFarm      with     PropNa as TopEnd.fill.backcolor.rgb
  ' to wobj as FredsFarm.TopEnd.fill.backcolor
  'and  Nsa(si) as "rgb" to CallByName from it

  For Si = 0 To UBound(NaA) - 1
     Set wObj = CallByName(wObj, NaA(Si), VbGet)
  Next Si
```

End If

PropDotVal = CallByName(wObj, NaA(Si), VbGet)
NotAvailable:

End Function

```
enter code here
```